# Android Real-time Notifications for Subscriptions only working for test notifications, not subscriptions

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I have an Android app with subscriptions. I can successfully start subscriptions from my app.

I have also setup Real-time developer notifications to handle renewable subscriptions on my server. This works fine when testing from Google Play "Send Test Notification". It's recieved to my webhook.

But I never get any calls to my webhook when I'm testing with subscriptions. I've made sure I finalize the transaction in the app, and the server sends an acknowledgement request too.

This is using the test payment card that always succeeds.

I don't understand why it's not working. Are pub/sub requests only sent to real subscriptions, and not test subscriptions with the test card?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like google made some unclear API...
You can have a notifications when you use a "slow" card, not an instant.

It work on my side when using "slow" payment test card.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327492/11173029

From what I have understood, in the real-world buisness logic, payment always take some time to get verified and you always get notifications, if someone can confirm it would be great!

[google play in-app purchase notification for pub/sub topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703639/google-play-in-app-purchase-notification-for-pub-sub-topic)